# How to add a custom command/alias like hello in fish shell?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, fedora, fish

I've made a new command/alias like `hello` in `/home/****/bin/hello`

when I execute as root user:

```
$ hello
```

it's output like:

```
Hello, the program executed by terminal command.
```

but when I execute with **fish** shell

```
$ hello
```

output

```
Failed to execute process '/home/***/bin/hello'. Reason:
exec: Exec format error
The file '/home/***/bin/hello' is marked as an executable but could not be run by the operating system.
```

I've searched in google but I'm not success.
No file or directory exist as `~/.config/fish/functions`

Please help me as I'm not expert in the Linux world.

Comment: Solution: `$ alias hello="execute the hello program"` 
then 
`$ function hello
   . /home/anowar/bin/hello 
 end`
then `$ funcsave hello`

Comment: Your solution is much more complicated than necessary. The issue is that your script (which is not an alias) is lacking a shebang line, so the kernel (which fish passes it to) does not know how to execute it. Either add `#!/bin/sh` (if you wrote an sh-compatible script) or execute it with `sh /path/to/hello`.